# Timeout::Error exception in a loop

Tags: ruby, exception, timeout

I have this piece of ruby code in a loop:

```
pid = Process.spawn("my_process_command")
begin
    Timeout.timeout(16) do
        `my_timeout_command`
        Process.wait(pid)
    end
rescue
    system("clear")
    puts 'Process not finished in time, killing it'
    Process.kill('TERM', pid)
end
```

The problem is that once the Timeout::Error exception has been caught the block will be skipped and the loop does practically nothing. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `rescue` specifically for `Timeout:Error` since [Timeout::Error is not a standard error](http://martinciu.com/2010/12/ruby-timeout-error-is-not-a-standard-error.html):

```
pid = Process.spawn("my_process_command")
begin
    Timeout.timeout(16) do
        `my_timeout_command`
        Process.wait(pid)
    end
rescue Timeout::Error
    system("clear")
    puts 'Process not finished in time, killing it'
    Process.kill('TERM', pid)
end
```

Comment: But doesn't [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html#method-c-timeout" say Timeout::Error is the default? 

timeout(sec, klass = nil)

Perform an operation in a block, raising an error if it takes longer than sec seconds to complete.

klass

    Exception Class to raise if the block fails to terminate in sec seconds. **Omitting will use the default, Timeout::Error.**

Comment: @user3606584 Yes, it means that you can call `Timeout.timeout(16, ProcessNotFinishedException)` and `ProcessNotFinishedException` will be raised instead of `Timeout::Error`